# how can I recursively iterate through an array of objects and get a new array with filtered data as a result

Tags: javascript, reactjs, methods, iteration

```
[
      {
      "id": "11ed-a261-0242ac120002",
      "name": "Languages",
      "code": 1,
      "description": "Here you can find teacher for any language. Learn when you want and how you want.",
      "childrenCategories": [
          {
          "id": "a261-0242ac120002",
          "name": "German",
          "code": 7,
          "description": "Here you can find teacher for German. Learn when you want and how you want.",
          "childrenCategories": []
          },
          {
          "id": "a261-0242ac120002",
          "name": "Spanish",
          "code": 8,
          "description": "Here you can find teacher for Spanish. Learn when you want and how you want.",
          "childrenCategories": []
          },
          ]
      },
      {
      "id": "a261-0242ac120002",
      "name": "Sciences",
      "code": 3,
      "description": "It is your online university. Learn whatever you want and become better.",
      "childrenCategories": [
          {
          "id": "6a66915a-3439-11ed-a261-0242ac120002",
          "name": "Mathematics",
          "code": 12,
          "description": "It is your online university. Learn Mathematics and become better.",
          "childrenCategories": []
          },
          {
          "id": "6a669420-3439-11ed-a261-0242ac120002",
          "name": "Physics",
          "code": 13,
          "description": "It is your online university. Learn Physics and become better.",
          "childrenCategories": []
          },
      ]
      },
  ]
```

I want to get such an array

```
[
    {"name": "Languages", "code": 1},
    {"name": "German", "code": 7},
    {"name": "Spanish", "code": 8},
    {"name": "Sciences", "code": 3},
    {"name": "Mathematics", "code": 12},
    {"name": "Physics", "code": 13,},
]
```

I have an array with nested objects and arrays that I want to recursively filter and return a new array without nesting that will only have the fields "name": "Languages" "code": 1,
I wrote the following code. He works. I want to know other options for solving this problem.

```js
const flatten = (arr) => {
    let result = []

    arr.flatMap((item) => {
        result.push({name: item.name, code: item.code})
        item.childrenCategories.map(child =>
            result.push({name: child.name, code: child.code})
        )
    })
    return result
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way of solving this problem using recursion:

```js
function flattenCategories(categories) {
  let result = [];

  function flatten(category) {
    const { name, code, childrenCategories } = category;
    result.push({ name, code });

    if (childrenCategories && childrenCategories.length > 0) {
      childrenCategories.forEach(child => flatten(child));
    }
  }

  categories.forEach(category => flatten(category));

  return result;
}

const data = [
  {
    "id": "11ed-a261-0242ac120002",
    "name": "Languages",
    "code": 1,
    "description": "Here you can find teacher for any language. Learn when you want and how you want.",
    "childrenCategories": [
      {
        "id": "a261-0242ac120002",
        "name": "German",
        "code": 7,
        "description": "Here you can find teacher for German. Learn when you want and how you want.",
        "childrenCategories": []
      },
      {
        "id": "a261-0242ac120002",
        "name": "Spanish",
        "code": 8,
        "description": "Here you can find teacher for Spanish. Learn when you want and how you want.",
        "childrenCategories": []
      },
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": "a261-0242ac120002",
    "name": "Sciences",
    "code": 3,
    "description": "It is your online university. Learn whatever you want and become better.",
    "childrenCategories": [
      {
        "id": "6a66915a-3439-11ed-a261-0242ac120002",
        "name": "Mathematics",
        "code": 12,
        "description": "It is your online university. Learn Mathematics and become better.",
        "childrenCategories": []
      },
      {
        "id": "6a669420-3439-11ed-a261-0242ac120002",
        "name": "Physics",
        "code": 13,
        "description": "It is your online university. Learn Physics and become better.",
        "childrenCategories": []
      },
    ]
  },
];

const result = flattenCategories(data);
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this?
This approach defines a recursive function `flattenRecursive` that iterates over each item in the array. If an item has children categories, the function recursively calls itself to flatten those categories as well. This way, you don't need to rely on array methods like `flatMap` or `map` to flatten the nested structure.

```
const flatten = (arr) => {
    let result = [];

    const flattenRecursive = (items) => {
        items.forEach(item => {
            result.push({ name: item.name, code: item.code });
            if (item.childrenCategories.length > 0) {
                flattenRecursive(item.childrenCategories);
            }
        });
    };

    flattenRecursive(arr);
    return result;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with a loop. if you need to handle large data it`s better to use iteration, but for most cases recursion is fine.

```js
const data = [
    {
        "id": "11ed-a261-0242ac120002",
        "name": "Languages",
        "code": 1,
        "description": "Here you can find teacher for any language. Learn when you want and how you want.",
        "childrenCategories": [
            {
                "id": "a261-0242ac120002",
                "name": "German",
                "code": 7,
                "description": "Here you can find teacher for German. Learn when you want and how you want.",
                "childrenCategories": []
            },
            {
                "id": "a261-0242ac120002",
                "name": "Spanish",
                "code": 8,
                "description": "Here you can find teacher for Spanish. Learn when you want and how you want.",
                "childrenCategories": []
            },
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "a261-0242ac120002",
        "name": "Sciences",
        "code": 3,
        "description": "It is your online university. Learn whatever you want and become better.",
        "childrenCategories": [
            {
                "id": "6a66915a-3439-11ed-a261-0242ac120002",
                "name": "Mathematics",
                "code": 12,
                "description": "It is your online university. Learn Mathematics and become better.",
                "childrenCategories": []
            },
            {
                "id": "6a669420-3439-11ed-a261-0242ac120002",
                "name": "Physics",
                "code": 13,
                "description": "It is your online university. Learn Physics and become better.",
                "childrenCategories": []
            },
        ]
    },
]


const res = data.reduce((acc, curVal) => {
    let stack = [curVal]
    while (stack.length > 0) {
        const {name, code, childrenCategories} = stack.shift()
        acc.push({name, code})
        if (childrenCategories.length > 0)
            stack.push(...childrenCategories)
    }
    return acc

},[])
console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `flatMap` to flatten the hierarchy, and object destructuring to extract the two needed pieces of information.

You could get to a one-liner without sacrificing readability:

```
let data = [...]
let extractedDetails = data.flatMap(category => [category].concat(category.childrenCategories)).map(({name, code}) => ({name, code}))
```